# How works cached event in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, events, page-lifecycle

I am wondering how asp.net **cached control event** works.I have read from some web resources that **cached events** are saved in the view state of the page but what like ?how the server knows the text has changed and then rises **text box** **text changed** event?on the server side we read information about **cached event** from **view state**  and how determine whether call the event or not.what kind of information view state  gives us about cached event?On the server what event handler method rises text chnged event

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h30h475z.aspx

Comment: Hi Aristos. The link you provide above is not related to my question

Comment: There are many cache, can you give some example with code to clarify what cache you talk about ?

Comment: For example selected index chanded even of dropdownlist is cached event.if we set autopostback property to true we convert cached event to postback event but if we set to false, the selected index changed event of dropdownlist cached and are stored in the viewstate of the page.I wonder how is stored in the viewstate of the page and retrived on the server and fire the selected change event

Comment: is there any one to answer this question ?